# Does EASA approve the use of localizer back course?

Tags: approach, easa, radio-navigation

Does EASA approve the use of [localizer back course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system#Localizer_back_course)? Are there some countries in Europe that allow it?

Comment: This would likely be only seen on specific instrument approaches/ILS setups, not as a blanket approval.  Is there a specific airport you're curious about?

Comment: Some countries do not allow the use of the ILS back course anywhere on their territory (e.g. UK) and I heard that EASA in general do not approved this use of the ILS so I was wondering if some countries do not follow the EASA rules on this on general perspective.

Comment: Take a look at [this forum discussion](https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/350881-back-course-localiser-approach-europe.html)

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you mean. If you mean "are they approved at EASA airports?" I can't help except to say that I have never seen a plate for one, flying into most EASA countries into a wide variety of airports.

If you mean "are EASA aircraft and pilots allowed to fly them in countries that do allow them?", I can tell you that in the Radio Navigation syllabus for the EASA ATPL exams there is a learning objective that the student must know what to set on an OBS or HSI to fly a back-beam localiser approach (if you want to check it's LO 062.02.05.02.08 in the new syllabus, 062.02.05.02.13 in the old one which is just about to go out but more widely available at the moment). This implies that flying one in an EASA-registered aircraft with an EASA licence and IR is not prohibited.